# Display < and > in Oracle XML Result

Tags: xml, oracle

I am using `XMLElement` and `XMLAgg` functions in Oracle 11g to generate an XML String. This XML String this then sent to another system for parsing. I want to append the following text to the result of my XML.

The problem is, if I append the text as is, the SQL Statement returns the following -

```
    <ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
      <TEST>
        <BATCH>
          &lt;BATCH_OBJECTS&gt;&lt;ORDER_NUM&gt; 0     &lt;/ORDER_NUM&gt;&lt;/BATCH_OBJECTS&gt;
        </BATCH>
      </TEST>
    </ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
```

I want the result to look like this -

```
    <ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
      <TEST>
        <BATCH>
          <BATCH_OBJECTS><ORDER_NUM>0</ORDER_NUM></BATCH_OBJECTS>
        </BATCH>
      </TEST>
    </ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
```

This is my query. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
    SELECT
    XMLElement("ZAVACOR_RESULTS",
    XMLAgg( 
        XMLElement("TEST",
            XMLElement("BATCH", (case when t.batch is NULL then '<BATCH_OBJECTS>            <ORDER_NUM> 0 </ORDER_NUM></BATCH_OBJECTS>' else t.batch end)),    
            (SELECT 
                XMLAgg( 
                    XMLElement("BATCH_OBJECTS",
                        XMLElement("ORDER_NUMBER", (case when bo.ORDER_NUMBER is NULL     then 0 else bo.ORDER_NUMBER end))  
                                )
                       )
             FROM BATCH_OBJECTS bo WHERE t.SAMPLE_NUMBER = bo.OBJECT_ID and                                     
             t.SAMPLE_NUMBER = 705000088556  and t.TEST_NUMBER = 4537048 
                          )
                         )
                    )
        ).getClobVal() as XML 
    FROM TEST T WHERE t.SAMPLE_NUMBER = 705000088556 and t.test_number = 4537048;
```

---

Data Relationships:

```
TEST.TEST_NUMBER ---Number, Primary Key
TEST.BATCH --- Varchar2, Can be NULL
TEST.SAMPLE_NUMBER --- Number

BATCH_OBJECTS.BATCH --- Varchar2, Part of Composite Key
BATCH_OBJECTS.ORDER_NUMBER --- Number, Part of Composite Key
```

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble with formatting the question. I want my result to look like this -                              <ZAVACOR_RESULTS>  <TEST>  <BATCH>
          <BATCH_OBJECTS><ORDER_NUM> 0 <ORDER_NUM><BATCH_OBJECTS>
        </BATCH>
      </TEST>
    </ZAVACOR_RESULTS>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need turn your fixed string into its own XML object. You haven't shown the table structures. If `test.batch` is a `varchar2` (rather than an `XMLType`) you can convert the result of your case:

```
SELECT
XMLElement("ZAVACOR_RESULTS",
XMLAgg( 
    XMLElement("TEST",
        XMLElement("BATCH", xmltype(case when t.batch is NULL then '<BATCH_OBJECTS>            <ORDER_NUM> 0 </ORDER_NUM></BATCH_OBJECTS>' else t.batch end)),    
...
```

If `test.batch` is an `XMLType` then just convert the string literal:

```
SELECT
XMLElement("ZAVACOR_RESULTS",
XMLAgg( 
    XMLElement("TEST",
        XMLElement("BATCH", case when t.batch is NULL then xmltype('<BATCH_OBJECTS>            <ORDER_NUM> 0 </ORDER_NUM></BATCH_OBJECTS>') else t.batch end),    
...
```

Either way these give:

```
XML
-------------------------------------------------------
<ZAVACOR_RESULTS><TEST><BATCH><BATCH_OBJECTS>
  <ORDER_NUM> 0 </ORDER_NUM>
</BATCH_OBJECTS>
</BATCH></TEST></ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd926/1).

---

Based on your description of what you're trying to do - which would be much easier to understand with sample data and expected output - I think what you really want is an outer join to the batch objects table, and an `NVL` of the order number in case there isn't one:

```
SELECT XMLSerialize(CONTENT
    XMLElement("ZAVACOR_RESULTS",
      XMLElement("TEST",
        XMLElement("BATCH",
          XMLElement("BATCH_OBJECTS",
            XMLAgg(
              XMLElement("ORDER_NUMBER", nvl(bo.ORDER_NUMBER, 0))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ) INDENT SIZE = 2
  ) as XML
FROM TEST T
LEFT JOIN BATCH_OBJECTS bo ON bo.BATCH = t.BATCH
WHERE t.SAMPLE_NUMBER = 705000088556
AND t.test_number = 4537048;
```

With `XMLSerialise` just to display neatly; to pass to another application you can stick with `getClobVal`:

```
<ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
  <TEST>
    <BATCH>
      <BATCH_OBJECTS>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>0</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </BATCH_OBJECTS>
    </BATCH>
  </TEST>
</ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
```

For a test with `batch_objects` records that gives:

```
<ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
  <TEST>
    <BATCH>
      <BATCH_OBJECTS>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>12345</ORDER_NUMBER>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>23456</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </BATCH_OBJECTS>
    </BATCH>
  </TEST>
</ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d18b/1).

If you want to combine multiple tests into one XML document you can have another level of `XMLAgg`:

```
SELECT XMLSerialize(CONTENT
    XMLElement("ZAVACOR_RESULTS",
      XMLAgg(
        XMLElement("TEST", XMLAttributes(t.TEST_NUMBER),
          XMLElement("BATCH", XMLAttributes(t.BATCH),
            XMLElement("BATCH_OBJECTS",
              XMLAgg(
                XMLElement("ORDER_NUMBER", nvl(bo.ORDER_NUMBER, 0))
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ) INDENT SIZE = 2
  ) as XML
FROM TEST T
LEFT JOIN BATCH_OBJECTS bo ON bo.BATCH = t.BATCH
GROUP BY t.TEST_NUMBER, t.BATCH;
```

I've included some attributes to distinguish the source rows:

```
<ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
  <TEST TEST_NUMBER="4537048">
    <BATCH>
      <BATCH_OBJECTS>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>0</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </BATCH_OBJECTS>
    </BATCH>
  </TEST>
  <TEST TEST_NUMBER="4537049">
    <BATCH BATCH="BATCH_1">
      <BATCH_OBJECTS>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>12345</ORDER_NUMBER>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>23456</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </BATCH_OBJECTS>
    </BATCH>
  </TEST>
</ZAVACOR_RESULTS>
```

[SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d18b/2).

Comment: I suspect you've made this more complicated than it needs to be, but without more sample input and output I'm not sure. The subquery in the middle looks odd, and the nesting of the elements looks strange too, if there is real data. I'd also probably use `nvl` instead of `case` here, just because it's shorter.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your reply. TEST.BATCH is a varchar2. If I use the XMLType function, I get the desired output when TEST.BATCH Is null. However, I get oracle parsing errors (ORA-31011, ORA-19202, ORA-06512)  if TEST.BATCH returns a value. Can I work around this?

Comment: Again, you haven't shown any sample data. That error suggests your `batch` column does not contain an XML-style snippet. So what are you really trying to do here? If batch is null - does that imply there are no `batch_object` records? The relationships aren't clear.

Comment: The real problem I am trying to solve is that if TEST.BATCH is NULL, the entire block following that (Select order_number from BATCH_OBJECTS) is also Empty since TEST.BATCH = BATCH_OBJECTS.BATCH. This is the reason I am trying to append the XML String <BATCH_OBJECTS><ORDER_NUM>0</ORDER_NUM></BATCH_OBJECTS>.